# Проблема со сменой image у picturebox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Столкнулся с проблемой, в pictureBox  по условию должен меняться Image, но при выполнении условия, выдаётся ошибка.[image: изображение импортировано]

Comment: Есть ли это изображение в папке проекта?

Comment: Нет, я думал что достаточно его имя указать, спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

у Вас есть папка проекта, где лежат *исходнки*.

При запуске VS компилирует проект, и кладёт *бинарник* внутрь папки `\bin\Debug` или что то в таком роде, куда вклюено еще и имя фреймворки и имя платформы (Intel-не интел).

Когда Вы в коде пишете имя файла без пути - то это означает, что програма при запуске будет искать этот файл *рядом с собой*, то есть, в однйо папке с бинарником.

Для этого нужно, чтобы файл туда попал.

Есть несколько способов сделать это:

1. Вручную. Не очень удобно
2. Добавив файл в проект, и поставив ему свойство "Content" и "Copy if newer" - тогда файл будет копироваться.

Посмотриет на картинике:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Определив так называемые "Pre-build" или "Post-build" события

второй способ - самый "прямой".

Успехов!